# Custom directive version of ng-repeat-start - ng-repeat-end

Tags: angularjs

I have a table that uses `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` every two table rows, like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>... // other <tr>'s without ng-repeat
    <tr ng-repeat-start="parameter in ctrl.parameters">
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>{{parameter.name}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-end>
        <td>Value</td>
        <td>{{parameter.value}}</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

This AngularJS application is deployed in Karaf as a Hawtio plugin and `ng-repeat-start-end` part doesn't work. Maybe because it's a plugin. Other table rows (without ng-repeat) works and shows the data `bind`ed. The odd thing is, a single entry for the label `Name` and `Value` still appears, but without the expression evaluated, whether there is or no data bound to the two element rows. What's the reason behind this?

I'm considering to use a custom directive in the js module instead of placing `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` in the html. Could someone show how to do this the custom directive way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my own question. Karaf's Hawtio uses AngularJS version 1.1.5 (as of this writing), which do not have `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end` yet. So, what I did is to enclose the repeating two rows in another `<tbody>` (multiple `<tbody>`s is working in HTML5) and put `ng-repeat` directive there. Like this:

```
    <tbody>
    .
    .
    .
    </tbody>
    <tbody ng-repeat="entry in data.entries">
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>{{entry.name}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Value</td>
            <td>{{entry.value}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```